# How do I Get Height & Width from an Uploaded image file

Tags: asp.net, file, upload, height, width

I am using ASP.NET 2.0. I am trying to get the height & width of an image file I uploaded using the FileUpload control. Once uploaded, the image is kept in the db, **not** the file system. It seems I should be able to use something like the following code to do this but I can't get it to work.

```
Dim strm As Stream = oPostedFile.InputStream
dim i as image
i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm)
```

Comment: Your tags are pretty inappropriate. Try:
ASP InputStream Images 
instead?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution.

```
Dim s As Stream = oPostedFile.InputStream
Dim i As Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(s)

intFileWidth = i.PhysicalDimension.Width
intFileHeight = i.PhysicalDimension.Height
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the Height and width of the image type file by the following code

```
System.Drawing.Image imgFile = 
System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fupDeviceImage.PostedFile.InputStream);
  if (imgFile.PhysicalDimension.Width > 500 || imgFile.PhysicalDimension.Height > 500)
  {
      cvDeviceImage.IsValid = false;
      fupDeviceImage.Focus();
      return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this Code you can see that uploaded image with their height and width and Convert it in to 400 to 800 pixel approximate*

![First of all you need these server controls to Upload and display image ...that is show in this link ][1]

> *[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0wNJ.png*

You also need one panel server control to add Image in page dynamically;

```
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    </asp:Panel>
```

Then add in the Asp.cs class code for the Button1_click:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = FileUpload1.FileName + "<br>" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType + "<br>" + FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
        string s = Request.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/upload/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        try
        {
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(s);
            Label1.Text += "<br>file upload success..";
            //For Get Uploaded Image height and Width :-
            System.Drawing.Image im = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
            double h = im.PhysicalDimension.Height;
            double w = im.PhysicalDimension.Width;
            Label2.Text = "Height:" + h + "...Widht: " + w;
            //For Display a Image in Panal control and set it height and width:-
            Image img = new Image();
            img.ImageUrl = "/upload/" + FileUpload1.FileName;
            if (h > w)
            {
                while (h > 800)
                {
                    h = h * 0.5;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (h > 400)
                {
                    h = h * 0.5;
                }
            }
            img.Height = new Unit(h);
            if (w > h)
            {
                while (w > 800)
                {
                    w = w * 0.5;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (w > 400)
                {
                    w = w * 0.5;
                }
            }
            img.Width = new Unit(w);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(img);
            Label2.Text += "<br>Now..Height:" + h + "...Widht: " + w;
        }
        catch
        {
            Label2.Text = "<br>choose your file..";
            Label1.Text = "";
        }
    }
```